# Teradata search for a string in reverse order

Tags: substring, teradata, reverse, substr

We're doing a conversion from MS SQL.
The original code is

> reverse(ltrim(rtrim(substring(reverse("string"),1,(charindex('
>   ',reverse("string")))))))

So what it does is that it searches for a string at the end until when it finds a space, it gets that string as its value

EX.

**'ABCD 123' the result is '123'**

**'STEP 12 3-2' the result is '3-2'**

So far I have this SELECT substr('ABCDE 1234', character('ABCDE 1234')-2) 
but don't know how to do a reverse search in Teradata :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**substr + instr**

```
select  'ABCD 123'                      as str
       ,substr(str,instr(str,' ',-1)+1) as token
;       

+----------+-------+
|   str    | token |
+----------+-------+
| ABCD 123 |   123 |
+----------+-------+
```

---

```
select  'STEP 12 3-2'                   as str
       ,substr(str,instr(str,' ',-1)+1) as token
;       

+-------------+-------+
|     str     | token |
+-------------+-------+
| STEP 12 3-2 |  3-2  |
+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Ops, I didn't notice this solution before, sorry.

Comment: No problem and I actually forgot the +1 for the instr

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

**Query:**

```
select strtok('STEP 12 3-2',' ',character_length('STEP 12 3-2') - character_length(Oreplace('STEP 12 3-2',' ',''))+1)
```

**Output:**

```
3-2
```

**Query:**

```
select strtok('ABCD 123',' ',character_length('ABCD 123') - character_length(Oreplace('ABCD 123',' ',''))+1)
```

**Output:**

```
123
```

strtok breaks string with specific delimiter, while character_length + oreplace will give us number of occurrence of "space".

Answer (score 0):

**regexp_substr** (very simple if you know regular expressions but comes with higher CPU cost)

```
select  'ABCD 123'                  as str
       ,regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]*$') as token
;       

+----------+-------+
|   str    | token |
+----------+-------+
| ABCD 123 |   123 |
+----------+-------+
```

---

```
select  'STEP 12 3-2'                   as str
       ,regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]*$') as token
;       

+-------------+-------+
|     str     | token |
+-------------+-------+
| STEP 12 3-2 |  3-2  |
+-------------+-------+
```